# USB class device for phone files sharing

Tags: android, class, arm, storage, stm32

I am looking for the description of the USB class implemented in android phones for when one wants to copy files after the phone is connected to the PC through USB:

[image]

Currently in my STM32 device I am using MSC but I find it unfitting. I needs a device class that will allow the MCU and the user (through PC USB connection) to manipulate the files simultaneously. This "phone" class device seems to be just that, but I cannot seem to find any info about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is Media Transfer Protocol (MTP), which is an extension of Picture Transfer protocol (PTP). As you've mentioned, it's used as it allows to transfer files atomically from and to the device while both ends may apply their own modifications. Some more information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

As a sidenote - I did at some point make my own implementation of FAT emulator over USB MSC which allowed the device to interfere with the data that's being transferred (both data content and metadata). In general hosts (Windows or Linux PC) don't like those to be modified and either error out when you do something really unexpected or simply don't see the changes because they cached them during first read and nobody expects the device to modify the data by itself.

Comment: Thanks for answer. MTP indeed seems to be the thing I was looking for. Unfortunately in STM32 it is only implemented as HOST library, not DEVICE... http://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105256.pdf I dont think I am able to write it from scratch. At the moment I struggle with problems connected to MSC (as you describe). Writing a glue-logic like lib fooling the Host USB controller to use internal FatFS instead of raw memory seems to be a way but I am not sure.

Comment: I did just that with MSC - by writing my own implementation of FAT - and it's likely not going to satisfy your needs as it's very limited in what you can actually do. For example during drive mount the OS (Windows) seems to cache the entire FAT table and assumes only the host modifies it. Therefore if you then go ahead and modify it (because you for example change the size of any file) it's going to be reading arbitrary data which isn't very far from greeting you with a big red error message about data being corrupted and unmounting you.

Comment: I see... In that case maybe the only way out of this is implementing the Device MSC class by myself. This however would be a long term task for me. Its to bad every time I get in reach of something it comes out that its not what I was looking for and I need to go further.

Comment: I haven't done the research when it comes to MTP, but sometimes you may find open source implementations in such cases. If not for STM32 to use directly, they may at least be used as a reference for your own implementation (Linux source for example). There's also ready paid implementations if you/your company are after that.